# How do I create a timeline based animation using createJS code in Adobe AnimateCC?

Tags: createjs

I want to tween using code inside Adobe AnimateCC by using createJS, but when I try and chain them together/animate objects in a sequence, I am running into trouble as they both start at the same time (rather than the square moving then the Circle moving), here is the open AnimateCC file: http://spectrumcreative.co.nz/stackOverflow/animateWithCode.fla and here is my code:

```
var targetSquare = this.square;
var tweenSquare = createjs.Tween.get(targetSquare, {loop: false})
.to({x: 300}, 1500, createjs.Ease.bounceOut)

var targetCircle = this.circle;
var tweenCircle = createjs.Tween.get(targetCircle, {loop: false})
.to({x: 300}, 1500, createjs.Ease.bounceOut)
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use **wait()**
I just made **animationTime**  variable for reuse, you can set any amount of time in **wait()**

```
var animationTime = 1500;
var targetSquare = this.square;
var tweenSquare = createjs.Tween.get(targetSquare, {loop: false}).to({x: 300}, animationTime, createjs.Ease.bounceOut)

var targetCircle = this.circle;
var tweenCircle = createjs.Tween.get(targetCircle, {loop: false}).wait(animationTime).to({x: 300}, animationTime, createjs.Ease.bounceOut);
```

This can be done also like this, so the second animation would start only after the first one is finished and **call()** will fire.

```
var animationTime = 1500;
var targetSquare = this.square;
var tweenSquare = createjs.Tween.get(targetSquare, {loop: false}).to({x: 300}, animationTime, createjs.Ease.bounceOut).call(function(){
    var targetCircle = this.circle;
    var tweenCircle = createjs.Tween.get(targetCircle, {loop: false}).to({x: 300}, animationTime, createjs.Ease.bounceOut);
});
```

Comment: Awesome that works really well, but I was wondering if you could share the "more advanced" option/options as well, as I would like to replicate what is available in the GSAP timeline but using createJS to avoid loading another library into AnimateCC.

Comment: @AlistairWalling I added the seconds example in the existing post.